# Error while executing an app in cordova

Tags: android, cordova

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAU04.png)

```
user@admin-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~/myapp$ cordova run androidRunning command: /home/user/myapp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/user/myapp
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: /home/user/myapp/platforms/android/cordova/run 
ERROR: Error: Please install Android target: "android-22".
```

Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: `/home/user/Android/android-sdk-linux/tools/android`
You will require:

1. "SDK Platform" for android-22
2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)

ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: /home/user/myapp/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project

Error: Error executing "google-chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/temp_chrome_user_data_dir_for_cordova http://localhost:8000/index.html": /bin/sh: 1: google-chrome: not found

```
at /home/user/myapp/platforms/browser/cordova/node_modules/cordova-serve/src/exec.js:34:26
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:758:5)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1183:11)
at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
at Pipe.close (net.js:485:12)
```

ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: /home/user/myapp/platforms/browser/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project

Comment: plz help me to fix this!!tried setting target=22

Answer (score 0):

Run (this is specific to your error, path may vary for others)

```
/home/user/Android/android-sdk-linux/tools/android
```

Verify that the following are currently installed:

"SDK Platform" for android-22

"Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)

"Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)